# Javascript: matrix operations for CSS transform perspective

Tags: javascript, matrix, css-transforms

I'm using [this script](https://github.com/arian/CSSMatrix/blob/master/CSSMatrix.js) that claims to implement matrix3d operation as described in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#recomposing-to-a-3d-matrix), however the script is missing matrix perspective operations, so I "cooked" something I'm not sure is either accurate or correct.

```
// the perspective matrix to multiply with
CSSMatrix.Perspective = function(x, y, z){
  var m = new CSSMatrix();
  m.m13 = x;
  m.m23 = y;
  m.m33 = z;
  return m;
};
```

and the method to use this matrix

```
// myMatrix.perspective(x,y,z); to apply a perspective matrix
CSSMatrix.prototype.perspective = function(x, y, z){
  if (y == null) y = 0;
  if (z == null) z = 0;
  return CSSMatrix.multiply(this, CSSMatrix.Perspective(x, y, z));
};
```

My question is, if `y` and `z` are `undefined`, what values should be used? Is it gonna be like rotate where `x` is used for all other axis, or 0 (zero) as in the above code?

I'm also not sure if `CSSMatrix.Perspective` matrix is properly written as described in the spec and implemented into the `CSSMatrix` prototype.

UPDATE:
I've found another implementation of the perspective functions (see below) and created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67z33jmp/) to demonstrate it's not working as well.

```
CSSMatrix.prototype.perspective = function(d){
  return CSSMatrix.multiply(this, CSSMatrix.Perspective(d));
};
CSSMatrix.Perspective = function(d){
  var m = new CSSMatrix(); 
  m.m43 = -1/d; 
  return m;
};
```

Why the two values are different please?

Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be how the 3d matrix is represented in the spec/docs (e.g. [Mozilla CDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d)) vs how it's represented in the CSSMatrix polyfill's [code](https://github.com/arian/CSSMatrix/blob/master/CSSMatrix.js). The code uses a transposed version of the matrix represented in the docs. The code works correctly but what the code refers to as the matrix position [3,4] is actually position [4,3] if we consider the maxtrix used in the spec/docs.

Regarding the formula for calculating perspective: as per the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/perspective), the following matrix should be used/multiplied for applying the perspective (`d` is the perspective value):

```
a1 a2 a3 a4    1 0  0   0
b1 b2 b3 b4 =  0 1  0   0
c1 c2 c3 c4    0 0  1   0
d1 d2 d3 d4    0 0 −1/d 1
```

So you were along the right path, but you were contructing the perspective matrix incorrectly because of the way the polyfill's code references the matrix internally. Instead of `m.m43 = -1/d;`, use `m.m34 = -1/d;`

I've updated the fiddle with the fixed code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/67z33jmp/2/).

Comment: Thanks so much, this really is busted, however, for some reason it's not working properly in my setup, it seems perspective must always be first in the object.

Comment: @thednp - i can confirm from my tests in the fiddle, perspective needs to be the first in the transform arguments.

Comment: Yes, will make sure to reorder object elements in the right order: perspective, rotate/skew, translate, scale ;thanks again.

Comment: I fixed the issue with order of properties, but I encountered another issue, perhaps you can have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892678/javascript-issue-with-360deg-rotations-and-matrix-composition

Answer (score 0):

As per the spec for the 'Perspective' property, it accepts only one parameter and that is 'length'. It doesn't accept, X, Y and Z.

Ref: [W3ORG - Perspective Property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#perspective-property)

Ref: [W3School's Perspective Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp)

I know, that I haven't given you the solution for your Perspective, but what's written is not the intended behavior. If my understanding about your question is wrong, please let me know, will try to help you with what I can. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer doesn't help, however I found something like this https://github.com/amadeus/transformer/blob/master/src/transformer.js#L528-L535 but it's not working addapting it to my code.

Comment: I've updated the question with new findings, can you please have a look?

Comment: Hello Friend, I looked at the new reference code that you have added. Looked at your fiddle too, but even after lots of effort, I couldn't get the exact answer. Am sorry for not being of any help to you. Wish you get the solution at the earliest. Thanks.