# Javascript: issue with 360deg rotations and matrix composition

Tags: javascript, matrix, css-transforms

I asked previously about the proper [function for perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654828/javascript-matrix-operations-for-css-transform-perspective) (to compute and compose a matrix), now I'm facing an older problem and I wasn't expecting this to be so much of an issue still.

Basically 360deg / 720deg is just zero and I don't know how to hack the following function to fix that.

```
CSSMatrix.Rotate = function(rx, ry, rz){
 rx *= Math.PI / 180;
 ry *= Math.PI / 180;
 rz *= Math.PI / 180;

 // minus sin() because of right-handed system
 var cosx = Math.cos(rx), sinx = - Math.sin(rx);
 var cosy = Math.cos(ry), siny = - Math.sin(ry);
 var cosz = Math.cos(rz), sinz = - Math.sin(rz);
 var m = new CSSMatrix();

 m.m11 = m.a = cosy * cosz;
 m.m12 = m.b = -cosy * sinz;
 m.m13 = siny;

m.m21 = m.c = sinx * siny * cosz + cosx * sinz;
m.m22 = m.d = cosx * cosz - sinx * siny * sinz;
m.m23 = - sinx * cosy;

 m.m31 = sinx * sinz - cosx * siny * cosz;
 m.m32 = sinx * cosz + cosx * siny * sinz;
 m.m33 = cosx * cosy;

 return m;
};
```

When using 360deg rotations (on any axis) to compose a matrix, the `CSSMatrix.rotate()` method is creating a rotation matrix and for each angle value we get `angle * Math.PI / 180` then other sinus / cosinus operations, but the matrix result is different from a computed transform of a regular `rotateX(360deg)`.

See my fiddles here where same code [doesn't work properly](https://jsfiddle.net/LuL3qoo4/) with 360deg angle and [working properly](https://jsfiddle.net/67z33jmp/2/) with angles different from 360deg.

How can I fix that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the precision supported by the `CSSMatrix` polyfill's code. It supports upto 6 decimals and truncates any lesser value (positive or negative) to 0 i.e. anything less than 0.000001 will be converted to 0.

In your fiddle, if you just apply the `rotateX(360deg)` transform, it converts to this matrix3d:

> matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -2.44929e-16, 0, 0, 2.44929e-16, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

The polyfill converts `-2.44929e-16` and `2.44929e-16` to `0` thereby generating this matrix3d:

> matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

Increasing the decimal precision in the polyfill's code fixes this issue. Change [line 35](https://github.com/arian/CSSMatrix/blob/master/CSSMatrix.js#L35) from:
`CSSMatrix.SMALL_NUMBER = 1e-6;`

to

`CSSMatrix.SMALL_NUMBER = 1e-20; // 20 decimal point precision`

I've fixed that in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/LuL3qoo4/1/) fiddle.

---

Edit: Regarding the question in the comment about different matrices being generated when applying rotate along 2 axes: This is because the `compose` function used in the fiddle applies rotation along all axes at the same time - which would be equivalent to a single `rotate3d(x, y, z)` call.

But the transforms applied via CSS in the fiddle rotate on the X and Z axes separately which would be equivalent to applying `rotate(x, 0, 0)` followed by `rotate(0, 0, z)`.

This can be verified by changing the `compose` function in the fiddle and comparing the matrix3d generated by the polyfill vs the one generated by the browser.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the approximation, now when adding an additional axis, say `rotateZ` the two matrix are very different. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/LuL3qoo4/2/